# Как сделать DrawerLayout под ToolBar?

Tags: android, xml, android-toolbar, android-xml, drawerlayout

у меня такой вопрос как сделать DrawerLayout под ToolBar.
Я задался таким вопрос ибо в DrawerLayout нету например как в RelativeLayout Below.
Вот сам xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"

        app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:padding="8dp" />


</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Дело в том что весь контент находится на ToolBar-e...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы должны переместить `DrawerLayout` в качестве верхнего родителя и вытащить из под его влияния тулбар, сделать это можно так:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/top_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/background_color" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/drawer"
            android:layout_width="260dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_marginTop="56dp" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Хотя по гайдам все должно быть под DrawerLayout а не над. [Источник_1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26985270/navigation-drawer-below-toolbar) и [источник_2](https://inducesmile.com/android-programming/how-to-add-navigation-drawer-below-toolbar-in-android/) которые помогут вам разобраться что и как делается.

Comment: Странно но говорит насчёт этого `<include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"` ошибку:`Cannot resolve symbol @layout/toolbar`

Comment: так конечно ошибка будет, если у вас нет такого layout-a, два варианта - добавьте layout в который будет отвечать за тулбар, либо сотрите эти строки и добавьте тулбар напрямую

Comment: А что делать если пишет ошибку `Element FrameLayout is not allowed here` также пишет про `ListView`...